# How do I set programmatically (C++) a breakpoint to the CreateProcessW, CreateProcessA, etc functions

Tags: c++, debugging, process, breakpoints, systems-programming

I have attached to a running process with DebugActiveProcess and I need to intercept CREATE_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT events.
It appears that usual WaitForDebugEvent doesn't catch creating of child processes.
I was [advised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19092925/does-debugactiveprocess-also-track-child-processes)  to set a bp to CreateProcessW function.

Could you please tell how to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Debug Break on Win32 Api functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080624/debug-break-on-win32-api-functions)

Comment: Unlikely a duplicate. That answer suggests using of command line debugger NTSD, but I asked how to do it from C++ program.